# Calling Microsoft graph API from dotnetcore app returns NotFound

Tags: .net-core, web-applications, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-files

I'm trying to get items from SharePoint using the Graph API in the name of the user, all these done inside a .net core 3.1 web app using oauth. When I request for specific items in a SharePoint document library I get the following ServiceException:

```
ex = {"Code: itemNotFound\r\nMessage: The resource could not be found.\r\nInner error:\r\n\tAdditionalData:\r\n\trequest-id: 7605d475-5967-481e-a16c-ab1fad610ef9\r\n\tdate: 2020-04-15T21:27:48\r\nClientRequestId: 7605d475-5967-481e-a16c-ab1fad610ef9\r\n"}
```

My calling function is the following:

```
var searchResult = await graphServiceClient
                    .Sites[$"{SharePointSiteId}"]
                    .Drives[$"{SharePointDocumentLibraryId}"]
                    .Items[$"{InvoicesFolderId}"]
                    .Children
                    .Request()
                    .GetAsync();
```

where:

- SharePointSiteId is a fully qualified SPS site Id
- SharePointDocumentLibraryId id of the document library
- InvoicesFolderId id of the folder in which I'd like to enumerate the children elements

The strange is that until I request for the Drive only:

```
var searchResult = await graphServiceClient
                    .Sites[$"{SharePointSiteId}"]
                    .Drives[$"{SharePointDocumentLibraryId}"]
                    .Request()
                    .GetAsync();
```

everything goes fine.

Strange thing 2: If I call the API using the Graph explorer with the same user in the same time using the Item identifier {InvoicesFolderId}, it gives back its children well.
Needless to say, the user can login to the SPS site and do whatever she wants. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to reproduce the same exception thrown when calling from Graph .Net SDK in C#.  Taking the exact same URL that is generated by SDK and testing in Graph Explorer is successful as well.  I would recommend opening an issue on the [Graph .Net SDK repo](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues).

Comment: Hey, thanks for reproducing this, I've added an issue [link](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/681) on the repo as well. We'll see if this is a bug really or not.